# how to insert 2 column in a file at hive location with delimiter using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, hive

I am writing kafka message to a file in hive warehouse location and with a message i also want to write the system_date with each record.

```
topicPartition=[TopicPartition(mytopic, p) for p in range(0,mytopicpartitions)]
consumer.assign(topicPartition)
consumer.seek_to_beginning()

print("start hive  connection")

conn = hive.Connection(host="xxxx", port=xx, username="xx",password="xx",auth="CUSTOM")

print("end hive connection")

f = open("/location/kafkafeed.txt",     "w")



# Reading and printing from the Kafka topic up to the desired limit
for msg in consumer:

# Extracting data in JSON format
payload = msg.value.decode('utf-8')

f.write(payload+"\t")   
print(f"writing into a file")
```

how should i write payload and date together?

Comment: If you're reading from Kafka and writing to Hive, you should really be using Pyspark for that... But you're not actually using your Hive connection variable in the code here, so what's your issue exactly?

Comment: so i am directly placing a file into hive warehouse location so that the data can be directly displayed into hive table.. inserting into a hive table taking a lot of time

Comment: So you did try using Spark? Not Python Hive client? Adding files to the warehouse directory completely bypasses the Hive Metastore. For that reason, it is not recommended. Interacting with the metastore adds latency, yes, (less if you use an actual MySQL/Postgres database than the default) but helps with other tasks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comments, Hive tables can read JSON. You don't need a delimiter.

You just have a string, not a dict you can add a date into.

You'll need to parse your json records first. For example

```
import json 

for msg in consumer:
    payload = json.loads(msg.value.decode('utf-8'))
    payload["date"] = msg.timestamp

    try:
        # TODO: write your payload somewhere
    except:
        break

# TODO: close the file/connection you're writing to
```

You should also subscribe the consumer, not assign it to any list of partitions manually